# Что вычисляет этот код?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, b, c = 1, i, k = 0;
    cin >> a;
    for (i = 10; i < 1010; i *= 10)
    {
        k++;
        if ((a - a % i) / i == 0)
            break;
    }
    for (k; k > 0; k--)
    {
        c += a % 10;
        a = (a - a % 10) / 10;
    }
    if (c != 1)
        cout << "Result is: " << c;
    else
        cout << "None";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: сумму последних трех цифр числа

Comment: @Grudy , начальное значение `c` - единица.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, суть это не меняет :)

Answer (score 1):

Не смог пройти мимо просто из-за кода из серии "зачем просто, если можно сложно" :)

Ваш код можно заменить вот таким

```
int main()
{
    int a, c = 1;
    cin >> a;
    for(int i = 3; i-->0; a/= 10) c += a%10;
    if (c != 1)
        cout << "Result is: " << c;
    else
        cout << "None";
}
```

Который точно так же выводит увеличенную на 1 сумму последних трех цифр числа *с учетом знака* (для -1234 равна -8), и выводит ее; для чисел, кратных 1000 и 0, пишет `None`.

Comment: Либо я чего-то не понимаю, либо код немного другой, ибо если я ввожу число например 123,то в моем коде выводит 7,а у вас 10

Comment: ??? https://ideone.com/nZe1ii - вот мой код, выводит 7...